# How to create correct output in when-otherwise?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the function `get_alerts` that returns two String fields. For simplicity let's consider the fixed output of this function: `return "xxx", "yyy"` (this is to avoid posting the code of `get_alerts`).

Then I have the `UDF` function and I use `when-otherwise` expression in Spark DataFrame `df`.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as func

get_alerts_udf = func.udf(lambda c1, c2, c3:
       get_alerts(c1, c2, c3),
       StructType(
                    [
                        StructField('probability', StringType()),
                        StructField('level', StringType())
                    ]
       )
    )

df = df \
    .withColumn("val", func.when(func.col("is_inside") == 1, get_alerts_udf(1,2,3))
                            .otherwise(["0","0"])
                )
```

The problem is that `otherwise(["0","0"])` does not correspond to the type of the output of the function `get_alerts_udf`.

How do I define `otherwise(["0","0"])` to correspond to:

```
      StructType(
                    [
                        StructField('probability', StringType()),
                        StructField('level', StringType())
                    ]
       )
```

**UPDATE:**

I still get the error:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve 'CASE WHEN (is_inside` = 1) THEN <lambda>(c1, c2, c3) ELSE named_struct('col1', '0', 'col2', '0') END' due to data type mismatch: THEN and ELSE expressions should all be same type or coercible to a common type;;`.
```

According to the recommendation from a duplicate post, I used `otherwise(func.struct(func.lit("xxx"),func.lit("yyy")))`.

Comment: I still get the error `pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve 'CASE WHEN (`is_inside` = 1) THEN <lambda>(c1, c2, c3) ELSE named_struct('col1', '0', 'col2', '0') END' due to data type mismatch: THEN and ELSE expressions should all be same type or coercible to a common type;;\`. I used `otherwise(func.struct(func.lit("xxx"),func.lit("yyy")))`

Comment: @user6910411: Can you please remove the duplicate tag?

Comment: Not `otherwise(func.struct(func.lit("xxx"),func.lit("yyy"))` but  `otherwise(func.struct(func.lit("xxx").alias("probability"), func.lit("yyy").alias("level")))`